# On Bartle's 'Elements of Integration' Exercise 7.U

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I haven't found a reference solution for this problem on the net, and I'm wondering whether my proof makes sense / is correct. Also I believe that it should be possible to find a simpler proof for the implication by using Vitali's Convergence theorem, but I'm not sure how.
Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

*Problem statement (adapted from original to make it self-contained; from R.G. Bartle 'The Elements of Integration', p.79, exercise 7.U):*

*Let $(X, \mathbf X, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $1 \leq p < \infty$. Let $\varphi$ be continuous on $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and satisfy the condition: $(*)$ there exists $K > 0$ such that $|\varphi(t)| \leq K |t|$ for $|t| \geq K$.
If $(f_n)$ converges to f in $L_p$ then $(\varphi \circ f_n)$ converges in $L_p$ to $\varphi \circ f$. Conversely, if condition $(*)$ is not satisfied, there exists a finite measure space and a sequence $(f_n)$ which converges in $L_p$ to $f$ but such that $(\varphi \circ f_n)$ does not converge in $L_p$ to $\varphi \circ f$.*

**Proof:**

$\Longrightarrow$

> (1. sequence and limit functions are in $L_p$ - implication in exercise 7.T)
>
> Let $M = \max_{t \in [0, K]} |\varphi(t)|^p$; ($M < \infty$ as $[0, K]$ compact and $\varphi$ continuous)
> $\Rightarrow$ $|\varphi \circ f|^p = |\varphi \circ f|^p (\chi_{|f|^{-1}([0, K[)} + \chi_{|f|^{-1}([K, \infty[)}) \leq M \chi_{|f|^{-1}([0, K[)} + K^p |f|^p \chi_{|f|^{-1}([K, \infty[)} \leq M + K^p |f|^p;$
> $\Rightarrow$ $||\varphi \circ f||_p^p = \int |\varphi \circ f|^p \mathrm d \mu \leq \int M + K^p |f|^p \mathrm{d} \mu = M \mu(X) + K^p ||f||_p^p < \infty$; (by $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $f \in L_p$)
>
> $(\Rightarrow \varphi \circ f \in L_p)$
> $(\mbox{by the same reasoning for } f_n \Rightarrow \varphi \circ f_n \in L_p, n \in \mathbb N)$
>
> (2. every subsequence has an $L_p$ convergent subsubsequence)
>
> Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb N$ be infinite;
> $\Rightarrow (f_n)_{n \in \Lambda}$ converges in $L_p$ to $f$;
> $\Rightarrow \exists \Lambda' \subset \Lambda$ infinite $ : f_n \rightarrow f \; \mu\mbox{-a.e.} \; (n \in \Lambda');$
>
> $\forall n \in \Lambda'$
>
> > $\Rightarrow \varphi \circ f_n \rightarrow \varphi \circ f \; \mu\mbox{-a.e.};$ (by continuity of $\varphi$)
> > $\Rightarrow \varphi \circ f_n \rightarrow \varphi \circ f$ almost uniformly; (by $\mu(X) < \infty$ and Egoroff's Theorem)
> >
> > Let $\delta > 0, E_{\delta} \subset X, \mu(E_{\delta}) < \delta : (\varphi \circ f_n |_{X \setminus E_{\delta}})$ converges uniformly to $\varphi \circ f |_{X \setminus E_{\delta}};$
> >
> > on $X \setminus E_{\delta}$
> >
> > > $\Rightarrow \exists N \in \Lambda' : (n > N \Rightarrow |f_n - f| \leq 1)$;
> > > Let $g = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} |f_n - f|^p + 1  \geq |f_n - f|^p$;
> > > $\Rightarrow g \in L_1$; (by $\mu(X) < \infty$)
> > > $\Rightarrow |f_n|^p = |f + (f_n - f)|^p \leq (2 \max\{|f|, |f_n - f|\})^p \leq 2^p(|f|^p + |f_n - f|^p) \leq 2^p(|f|^p + g)$;
> > > $\Rightarrow |\varphi \circ f_n|^p \leq M + K^p |f_n|^p \leq M + K^p 2^p (|f|^p + g) \in L_1;$ (again by $\mu(X) < \infty$)
> > > $\Rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f_n||_p \rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f||_p$; (by Lebesgue Dominated convergence Theorem)
> >
> > $\Rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f_n||_p \rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f||_p \;$ on $X \setminus E$ where $E = \bigcap_{\delta > 0} E_{\delta}$;
> > $\Rightarrow \forall \delta > 0 \; E \subset E_{\delta} \Rightarrow \mu(E) \leq \mu(E_{\delta}) < \delta \Rightarrow \mu(E) = 0;$
> > $\Rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f_n||_p \rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f||_p \;$ on $X$;
>
> ($\Rightarrow \forall \Lambda \subset \mathbb N $ infinite $\, \exists \Lambda' \subset \Lambda : (\varphi \circ f_n)_{n \in \Lambda'}$ converges in $L_p$ to $\varphi \circ f$);
>
> (3. sequence converges in $L_p$)
>
> Suppose $\varphi \circ f_n \nrightarrow \varphi \circ f$ in $L_p$;
> $\Rightarrow \exists \epsilon >0 : \forall N \in \mathbb N \, \exists n > N : ||f_n - f||_p \geq \epsilon;$
> Let $\Lambda = \{n \in \mathbb N \mid ||f_n - f||_p \geq \epsilon\};$
> $\Rightarrow (\varphi \circ f_n)_{n \in \Lambda}$ is a subsequence which does not posses an $L_p$ convergent subsubsequence, contrary to what was proven before.
> $(\Rightarrow \varphi \circ f_n \rightarrow \varphi \circ f$ in $L_p)$

$\Longleftarrow$

> (1. construction of finite measure space and limit function - converse in exercise 7.T)
>
> $\lnot (*) \Rightarrow \forall K > 0 \; \exists |t| \geq K: |\varphi(t)| > K |t|$;
> Let $t_n \in \mathbb R, t_n > n, |\varphi(t_n)| > n |t_n|, n \in \mathbb N$; 
> Let $(X = \mathbb N, 2^{\mathbb N}, \mu)$ be a measure space with measure $\mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E} \frac 1 {{|t_n|}^p n^2}$;
> $\Rightarrow \mu(X) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac 1 {{|t_n|}^p n^2} \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac 1 {n^2} < \infty$ ($\Rightarrow$ the measure space is finite);
> Let $f:\mathbb N \ni n \mapsto t_n$;
> $\Rightarrow ||f||_p^p = \int |f|^p \mathrm d \mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|f(n)|^p} {{|t_n|}^p n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2} < \infty;$
> $\Rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f||_p^p = \int |\varphi \circ f|^p \mathrm d \mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\varphi(f(n))|^p} {{|t_n|}^p n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\varphi(t_n)|^p} {{|t_n|}^p n^2} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n^{(2-p)}} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n} = \infty;$
> $(\Rightarrow f \in L_p \, \land \, \varphi \circ f \notin L_p)$
>
> (2. construction of sequence)
>
> Let $f_n = (1 - \frac 1 n) f, \, n \in \mathbb N$;
> $\Rightarrow ||f_n||_p = ||(1-\frac 1 n)f||_p = (1-\frac 1 n)||f||_p < \infty \Rightarrow f_n \in L_p \; \forall n \in \mathbb N;$
> $\Rightarrow ||f_n - f||_p = \frac 1 n ||f||_p \rightarrow 0;$ ($f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L_p$)
>
> Suppose $\varphi \circ f_n \rightarrow \varphi \circ f$ in $L_p$;
> $\Rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb N \; ||\varphi \circ f||_p \leq ||\varphi \circ f_n||_p + ||\varphi \circ f_n - \varphi \circ f||_p < \infty;$(by Minkowski Inequality)
> $\varphi \circ f \notin L_p \Rightarrow$ contradiction.
> ($\Rightarrow \varphi \circ f_n \nrightarrow \varphi \circ f$ in $L_p$)

$\square$

Comment: I agree $$||\varphi \circ f_n\chi_{E_\delta^C}||_p \rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f\chi_{E_\delta^C}||_p$$ for every $\delta>0$ because of LDC.  Why does this imply that  $||\varphi \circ f_n\chi_{(\cap_\delta E_\delta)^C}||_p \rightarrow ||\varphi \circ f\chi_{(\cap_\delta E_\delta)^C}||_p$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You proof is very creative and I found it extremely beautiful. You have some real taste in measure theory, but I have some doubts on step 2 from moving to convergence on $E_\delta$ to convergence in $E$, maybe it is just me being slow. In any case, we can avoid this step using Vitali's Theorem.

---

You already proved there is a subsequence such that $\varphi\circ f_n \xrightarrow[]{a.e.} \varphi \circ f$ where the convergence is pointwise almost everwhere. Hence, by Ergoroff, we already have that $\varphi \circ f_n \xrightarrow[]{a.u.} \varphi \circ f $ and $\varphi \circ f_n \xrightarrow[]{\mathcal{M}} \varphi \circ f $. Using Vitali's Theorem, to prove $\varphi \circ f_n \xrightarrow[]{L_p}\varphi \circ f$ it remains to prove:

$ii)$ $\exists E_\epsilon $ with $\mu(E_\epsilon)<\infty$ such that $\int_{E_\epsilon^C} |\varphi \circ f_n|^pd\mu <\epsilon^p$.

Because we are in a finite measure space, this is trivial, we may take $X=E_\epsilon$.

$iii)$ For each $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that if $\mu(E)<\delta$, $\int_E | \varphi \circ f_n|^pd\mu< \epsilon^p$.

$$\int_E | \varphi \circ f_n|^pd\mu=\int_{E \cap\{x:\: |f_n|\geq K\}}| \varphi \circ f_n|^pd\mu+\int_{E \cap\{x:\: |f_n|\leq K\}}| \varphi \circ f_n|^pd\mu\leq$$
$$\int_{E \cap\{x:\: |f_n|\geq K\}}K^p| f_n|^pd\mu+\int_{E\cap \{x:\: |f_n|\leq K\}} K^p d\mu\leq K^p\int_E|f_n|^p d\mu +\mu(E) K^p $$

Because $f_n \xrightarrow[]{L_p} f$ if $\delta$ is small (by Vitalli), we can make
$\int_{E}|f_n|^pd\mu<\epsilon^p/2$ provided $\mu(E)<\delta$. The term without the integral is also easily controlled by making $\delta $ small. Hence,  we have $\varphi \circ f_n\xrightarrow[]{L_p} \varphi \circ f$

---

Convergence in $L_p$ was proved for a subsequence. To prove $\varphi \circ f_n\xrightarrow[]{L_p} \varphi \circ f$ we argue  exactly as you did on step 3.